# Type inference in GHCi vs. manual signature

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghc, ghci

when I type

```
:t map length . sum
```

into GHCi, it says that the type would be:

```
map length . sum :: Num [[a]] => [[[a]]] -> [Int]
```

However, if I create a file `type-test.hs` containing

```
x :: Num [[a]] => [[[a]]] -> [Int]
x = map length . sum
```

both ghc and ghci complain:

```
type-test.hs:1:1:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [[a]]
    (Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)
    In the type signature for `x': x :: Num [[a]] => [[[a]]] -> [Int]
```

Why does ghci allow me to infer the type for this (using :t), when FlexibleContexts are not enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(This doesn't answer your original question, but solves the problem with the code instead)

These errors hint at that your code as written probably isn't what you meant. This code:

```
map length . sum
```

means "Take my list of numbers, and sum it, then compute the length of each element(??) of the resulting number." That makes no sense.

You probably meant:

```
sum . map length
```

which means "Take my list of lists, compute the length of every element, and sum the lengths."

What the error message itself means is that since `sum` returns a number, aka the type of `sum` is `Num n => [n] -> n`, and you then try to use `map length` on that, which has type `Num m => [[a]] -> [m]`, the compiler tries to say that `n == [[a]]` to make the types match, and everything goes downhill from there.

Answer (score 10):

First, let's clarify one thing. What happens if we define the function in GHCi, rather than querying the type?

```
> let x = map length . sum :: (Num [[a]]) => [[[a]]] -> [Int]
<interactive>:0:9:
    Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [[a]]
    (Use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this)
    In an expression type signature: Num [[a]] => [[[a]]] -> [Int]
```

And so on. In other words, the same thing. What if we let GHCi infer the type of the definition?

```
> let x = map length . sum
<interactive>:0:22:
    No instance for (Num [[a0]])
      arising from a use of `sum'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num [[a0]])
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `sum'
    In the expression: map length . sum
```

This is roughly the same error that results from loading a file containing the definition without a type signature.

What's the upshot of all this? Well, think about the fact that it *tells* you what extension is needed. GHC is capable of recognizing what the type *means*, even if it rejects the type by default. I'd hardly expect GHC to use a completely different type checker depending on the combination of extensions used, so it seems easy to conclude that the offending type is being rejected for no reason other than the relevant extension being disabled.

The `:t` command in GHCi isn't part of the compilation process--it's a hotline to the type checking and inference system, letting you ask the type of hypothetical code. There's no obvious reason for it to restrict itself arbitrarily based on extensions, when a more general type could still be informative, for the same reason that the error messages above tell you `use -XFlexibleContexts to permit this` rather than merely `syntax error in type constraint`.

---

As a possibly more interesting aside, there are also cases where an inferred type will be accepted happily by the compiler, but the inferred type can't actually be written out explicitly for one of several reasons.

For instance, disabling the monomorphism restriction will allow your example to have its type inferred (matching what `:t` says), despite that type requiring an extension to write manually.

Another example are definitions in the `where` clause of a function definition which make use of polymorphic arguments to the parent function. Their own types are not polymorphic, being dictated by the arguments received in the outer scope, yet the type variables in the parent function's signature are not in scope for the `where` clause¹. There may be other examples as well.

¹ The type variables from the parent's signature can be brought into scope with the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension and an explicit `forall`, if that's needed.

Comment: Note, however, that `ghci> let x = map length . sum` works if the monomorphism restriction is disabled, and `ghci> let x xs = map length (sum xs)` works also with the MR. The ghci-error for the first is only due to trying to monomorphise the type according to the defaulting rules.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yeah, I realized as soon as I posted that I should clarify that, heh. The point about un-writable types is an interesting addendum, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to look at it:

Haskell tells you that your expression had a valid type, namely `[[[a]]] -> [Int]` if only `[[a]]` would be an instance of `Num`.

This is like some girls telling you she will go out with you when *hell freezes over*. You wouldn't complain that she *promised to go out with me* despite the *hell can freeze over* possibility is not given in this world, would you? You would rather notice that she just said **No** in a more or less polite way.

Comment: `[[a]]`` can be made an instance of Num in many different useful ways. E.g. [[Int]] could be an (unsafe) integer matrix so the _hell freezes over_ argument doesn't hold.

Comment: Nitpicking cyrillic professor: please take note that having `Num [[Int]]` does not mean having `Num [[a]]`

Comment: @Ingo, we don't have a `Num a` either, but that doesn't make values of types like `Num a => a` useless. LOL @ the great analogy, btw! :D @nponeccop, I'm sure there is a (possibly unsafe) way to change the climate in hell too!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the function is perfectly acceptable, but its most general type is not allowed to be specified by the language grammar. What could `ghci` do in such circumstances? I can only think of two options, either give a type that can only be specified with some extension enabled, or giving an error. Giving an error without mentioning that it can be fixed by enabling an extension seems not very desirable to me. Just having `:t` report the inferred most general type is simpler, and quite possibly when the feature was implemented, nobody thought of situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

See http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules

Comment: I'm not sure how type defaulting is particularly relevant here...?